# Creating a new variable that flags every instance of a change in absolute value in R

Tags: r

I'm working with processed data from motion sensors and would like some help manipulating the dataset. My variables include "Time" (in milliseconds) and "Shoulder Flexion" (in angles). I want to create a new variable that flags every time there is an absolute value change of 3 degrees in the "Shoulder Flexion" variable. Something like:

```
newdata <- mydata %>%
    mutate(changevariable = ifelse(Shoulder.Flexion = [absolute value change in 3 degrees], "1", "0")
```

, where each flag/"1" is in a sequence of ± 3 degrees.

An example of my dataset:

```
structure(list(Time = c(0, 0.0078125, 0.015625, 0.023438, 0.03125, 
0.039062, 0.046875, 0.054688, 0.0625, 0.070312, 0.078125, 0.085938, 
0.09375, 0.10156, 0.10938, 0.11719, 0.125, 0.13281, 0.14062, 
0.14844), Shoulder.Flexion = c(-9.4721, -12.098, -12.51, 12.253, 
11.815, 11.385, 11.03, 10.766, 10.586, 10.472, 10.408, 10.381, 
10.383, 10.407, 10.453, 10.521, 10.605, 10.695, 10.778, 10.846
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")
```

This point of this is to help me generate a value of the number of times a subject rotates 3 degrees in a specified time interval. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, the dataset I'm working with has thousands of observations (in degrees) for every 8 milliseconds. What I'm looking for is a variable that denotes a cumulative rotation of three degrees that starts over each time there's a ≥3 degree rotation (after each "1"). So, if the angle variable goes from: 9.2, 10.2, 11.2, 12.2, 13.2, 14.2, 15.2 the variable would be coded 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the amount of data you have you could consider a loop. I do try to avoid `for` loops in general and do think a `data.table` solution would probably be more helpful and preferable.

```
mydata$Shoulder.Flexion = c(9,10,10.5,11.7,12.1,13,13.5,14,15.9,16.2,17.4,18.6,19,18.5,17.5,17,15,14,13,12)

ref = mydata[1,2]
mydata$changevariable <- 0

for (i in 2:nrow(mydata)) {
  if (abs(mydata[i, 2] - ref) >= 3) {
    mydata[i, "changevariable"] <- 1
    ref = mydata[i, 2]
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
        Time Shoulder.Flexion changevariable
1  0.0000000              9.0              0
2  0.0078125             10.0              0
3  0.0156250             10.5              0
4  0.0234380             11.7              0
5  0.0312500             12.1              1
6  0.0390620             13.0              0
7  0.0468750             13.5              0
8  0.0546880             14.0              0
9  0.0625000             15.9              1
10 0.0703120             16.2              0
11 0.0781250             17.4              0
12 0.0859380             18.6              0
13 0.0937500             19.0              1
14 0.1015600             18.5              0
15 0.1093800             17.5              0
16 0.1171900             17.0              0
17 0.1250000             15.0              1
18 0.1328100             14.0              0
19 0.1406200             13.0              0
20 0.1484400             12.0              1
```

**Edit**:

It is still unclear what is desired. It would help to have a "final" desired dataframe that includes the `changevariable` for your sample data. It also might help to have different sample data that has more changes in it too that exceed 3 degrees.

Here is another version in base R that calculates differences between rows, takes the absolute value of those differences, and then steps through those differences to calculate cumulative sum. When the sum is greater than 3, then `changevariable` is set to 1, and the cumulative sum is reset to zero.

Let me know if this is closer:

```
mydata$diff <- ave(mydata$Shoulder.Flexion, FUN = function(x) c(0, abs(diff(x))))

total = 0
mydata$changevariable <- 0

for (i in 2:nrow(mydata)) {
  total <- total + mydata[i, "diff"]
  if (total >= 3) {
    mydata[i, "changevariable"] <- 1
    total = 0
  }
}

        Time Shoulder.Flexion    diff changevariable
1  0.0000000          -9.4721  0.0000              0
2  0.0078125         -12.0980  2.6259              0
3  0.0156250         -12.5100  0.4120              1
4  0.0234380          12.2530 24.7630              1
5  0.0312500          11.8150  0.4380              0
6  0.0390620          11.3850  0.4300              0
7  0.0468750          11.0300  0.3550              0
8  0.0546880          10.7660  0.2640              0
9  0.0625000          10.5860  0.1800              0
10 0.0703120          10.4720  0.1140              0
11 0.0781250          10.4080  0.0640              0
12 0.0859380          10.3810  0.0270              0
13 0.0937500          10.3830  0.0020              0
14 0.1015600          10.4070  0.0240              0
15 0.1093800          10.4530  0.0460              0
16 0.1171900          10.5210  0.0680              0
17 0.1250000          10.6050  0.0840              0
18 0.1328100          10.6950  0.0900              0
19 0.1406200          10.7780  0.0830              0
20 0.1484400          10.8460  0.0680              0
```

Comment: Thanks! Sorry - I realized that what I meant was: If the sum of the differences between the rows, starting from the 2nd row - the 1st row (converted into absolute values)  ≥3, "1". For example, here's the structure when the absolute differences paired with time: structure(list(Time = c(0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.06, 0.07, 0.08, 0.09, 0.09, 0.1, 0.11, 0.12, 0.12, 0.13, 
0.14, 0.15), absdiff = c(0, 3.13, 2.3, 17.14, 1.05, 0.73, 0.52, 
0.38, 0.29, 0.22, 0.18, 0.15, 0.13, 0.1, 0.09, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I tried editing the for loop to no avail: ref = mydata[2,2]
mydata$changevariable <- 0

for (i in 2:nrow(mydata)) {
  if(sum(mydata[i, 2]) >= 3) {
    mydata[i, "changevariable"] <- 1
    ref = mydata[i, 2]
  }
}

Comment: @mkpcr please see edited answer (the bottom) - it might help to have a complete 'final' or desired dataframe with `changevariable` too. Hope this is closer to what you need, let me know.